# Save Aggregate Report in JMeter when multiple thread

Tags: performance, testing, jmeter, automated-tests, jmeter-5.0

I have my Test Plan which includes one Thread Group with 10 Number of Threads (users).

When I launch the Test Plan with an Aggregate Report, I have one row with an Average column that interests me.

But when I record it atomically in this way :

[image]

The report breaks down into 10 rows (the number of threads), and I lose the average.

How can I save the Aggregate Report as it is displayed in the JMeter interface?

Thanks